# Which functions or what things to write in service layer Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose i have `class USER` with attributes.

In some examples i see `UserService class` defined for some functions.

I am confused which things or functions should written in User Class and which things in UserService.

For e,g If i want to write some function To Validate users in database like

```
validate(user,pass)
```

Where should write those function

Also if i have `class ShoppingProducts`

and i want to get all prodcuts shopped by particular user in which class should i write that function i mean in `product class or UserService or ProductService`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical example of domain model vs anemic model.

There's a lot of theory in this discussion, but a practical advice from me is to:

- put all methods that can operate on the `User` properties *only* in the `User` class.
- put all methods that require database access, accessing web services, or other layers, in the service.

[See this](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=180) related article of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into the battle of domain vs anemic or SOA data separate from behavior.

I will say that I think of service's as behavior that spreads across multiple domains (multiple domain objects) and deals with data transfer objects (ie don't put the DTOs in your domain objects).

With REST being so popular these days and the fact the Resources (REST since) are not Models you always seem to need DTOs and Service classes.

On other hand with AspectJ, Annotations and some other magic you can really push the edge of Domain Driven design but I still think you should not reference other domain objects in a domain object.